# Using Capistrano to deploy rails app in remote DreamHost testing/sandbox server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano, dreamhost, testing-strategies

Currently I use capistrano to deploy my app to a remote production server in Dreamhost ([see this guide](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/14/deploying-rails-on-dreamhost-with-passenger/)).

I would like to setup an alternate sub-domain (testing.example.com) in my DH setup as a sandbox enviroment for beta testing. I'm currently running Rails 2.3.10.

The Capistrano task must force RAILS_ENV to "testing". Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Capistrano's [Multistage extension](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension)